# Compounding interest program in Java

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

I'm trying to write this compounding interest program with a do while loop at the end and I cannot figure out how to print out the final amount.

Here is the code I have so far :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double amount;
    double rate;
    double year;

    System.out.println("This program, with user input, computes interest.\n" +
    "It allows for multiple computations.\n" +
    "User will input initial cost, interest rate and number of years.");

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What is the initial cost?");
    amount = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("What is the interest rate?");
    rate = keyboard.nextDouble();
    rate = rate/100;

    System.out.println("How many years?");
    year = keyboard.nextInt();


    for (int x = 1; x < year; x++){
        amount = amount * Math.pow(1.0 + rate, year);
                }
    System.out.println("For " + year + " years an initial " + amount + " cost compounded at a rate of " + rate + " will grow to " + amount);


    String go = "n";
    do{
        System.out.println("Continue Y/N");
        go = keyboard.nextLine();
    }while (go.equals("Y") || go.equals("y"));
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is, `amount = amount * Math.pow(1.0 + rate, year);`.  You're overwriting the original amount with the calculated amount.  You need a separate value to hold the calculated value while still holding the original value.

So:

```
double finalAmount = amount * Math.pow(1.0 + rate, year);
```

Then in your output:

```
System.out.println("For " + year + " years an initial " + amount + 
    " cost compounded at a rate of " + rate + " will grow to " + finalAmount);
```

EDIT: Alternatively, you can save a line, a variable, and just do the calculation inline, as such:

```
System.out.println("For " + year + " years an initial " + amount + 
    " cost compounded at a rate of " + rate + " will grow to " + 
    (amount * Math.pow(1.0 + rate, year)));
```

Comment: Doing the calculation inline fixed everything! Doing it the other way was giving me the error of "unknown variable of finalAmount"

Comment: @MicahCalamosca Oh, sorry.  In order to do it the first way, with `finalAmount`, you need to declare the `finalAmount` variable, like you declared all the other variables.  Anyway, I'm glad you got it working.  If you used my solution, please accept it as an answer.  Thanks.